# Square-tree using maps and recursion

Tags: recursion, lisp, scheme, sicp

> Define a procedure square-tree analogous to the
>   square-list procedure of exercise
>   2.21. That is, square-list should behave as follows:
>
> ```
> (square-tree  (list 1
>         (list 2 (list 3 4) 5)
>         (list 6 7))) (1 (4 (9 16) 25) (36 49))
> ```
>
> Define square-tree both directly
>   (i.e., without using any higher-order
>   procedures) and also by using map and
>   recursion.

I wrote this solution.  What do you think?

```
(define (square x) (* x x))

(define (square-tree tree)
  (cond ((null? tree) null)
        ((pair? tree)
         (cons (square-tree (car tree)) 
               (square-tree (cdr tree))))
        (else (square tree))))

(define (map-square-tree tree)
  (map (lambda (subtree)
         (if (pair? subtree)
             (cons (square-tree (car subtree))
                   (square-tree (cdr subtree)))
             (square subtree)))
       tree))

(define a (list 1 1 (list (list 2 3) 1 2)))
```

**EDIT:** This is a much better solution for map-square-tree.

```
(define (square x) (* x x))

(define (square-tree tree)
  (cond ((null? tree) null)
        ((pair? tree)
         (cons (square-tree (car tree)) 
               (square-tree (cdr tree))))
        (else (square tree))))

(define (map-square-tree tree)
  (map (lambda (subtree)
         ((if (pair? subtree) map-square-tree square) subtree))
       tree))

(define a (list 1 1 (list (list 2 3) 1 2)))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your direct definition of `square-tree` is correct.

Your definition using `map` calls `square-tree`; to make it properly recursive, call `map-square-tree` instead.  Further, you may recurse on the `subtree` itself.  This will make your code succinct.

```
(define (map-square-tree tree)
  (map (lambda (subtree)
         ((if (pair? subtree) map-square-tree square) subtree))
       tree))
```